# Push notification to IOs or Android from django webapp

Tags: django, push-notification

I have my Django Web app and I want to make a mobile version but it will take me a while, so, I would like to know if it is possible to send push notifications to the mobile phone (either Android, Apple) from the webapp.

The client will run the website normally from the phone and I would like to send a notification when the process made is finished. How can I achieve that ? Do django signals have the effect of push notification ?

Thanks

Comment: You could write a function return data, such as json data, and then use a `listen event` to check the data on mobile phone

Answer (score 0):

You can connect QuickBlox to your app and that would be a way to go.
Here's the tutorial for iOS: http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-messages_users-ios
And this one is for Android: http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-messages_users-android
Hope that helps.